# Error while parsing JsonObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get JsonObject from  DownloadTask. But I am getting array values that are stored in downloadData along with JsonObjects stored in jsonObjectText.     Look at below in logs.     ***Why my code return array with JsonObject***, But I only log the content of the jsonObject variable.

Here picture of Logs:

[image: Logs]

Here is my Code :

```
package com.example.smarpitsingh.webview;  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    String name = "Result";
    String result = "",downloadedData,jsonObjectText;
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    InputStream inputStream;
    InputStreamReader streamReader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        try {
            downloadedData = downloadTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty").get();

           JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(downloadedData);

           for (int i=1; i<20; i++){

               DownloadTask jasonTask = new DownloadTask();
                jsonObjectText = jasonTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/"+jsonArray.getString(i)+".json?print=pretty").get();

               Log.i(name,jsonObjectText);
            }


        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = streamReader.read();
                while (data != -1){
                    char count = (char)data;
                    result += count;
                    data = streamReader.read();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return result;
        }
    }
`}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have got an array in your json:
[image]

Comment: Can you help me with another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743749/i-am-stuck-here-in-testing-rxjava-with-mvp