# Unit testing RxJava in MVP presenter in android

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, rx-java, integration-testing, rx-java2

I am new to TDD. Also new to MVP and Rxjava. I just dive into it and It is worth it. But I stuck at the testing part. I understand the basis of unit testing. It is a little bit difficult for me in beginning. But I stuck here and So how can test the presenter?

Here is the Presenter class -

```
public class NewsPresenter {

private final RxjavaService service;
private final MainView view;
private CompositeSubscription subscriptions;

public NewsPresenter(RxjavaService service, MainView view) {
    this.service = service;
    this.view = view;
    subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
}

public void getNewsList(String urlQ){
    view.showWait();

    Subscription subscription = service.getNews(urlQ ,new RxjavaService.GetNewsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Articles articles) {
            view.removeWait();
            view.getNewsListSuccess(articles);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(NetworkError networkError) {
            view.removeWait();
            view.onFailure(networkError.getAppErrorMessage());
            Log.i("huh",networkError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    subscriptions.add(subscription);
}

public void onStop(){
    subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

}

Here is the View Interface -

```
public interface MainView {

void showWait();

void removeWait();

void onFailure(String appErrorMessage);

void getNewsListSuccess(Articles articles);
```

}

Here is the RxJavaService class -

```
public class RxjavaService {

private final NewsRestService newsRestService;

public RxjavaService(NewsRestService newsRestService) {
    this.newsRestService = newsRestService;
}


public interface GetNewsCallback {
    void onSuccess(Articles articles);

    void onError(NetworkError networkError);
}


public Subscription getNews(String q, final GetNewsCallback getNewsCallback) {
    Log.i("stuck","service called");
    return newsRestService.getNewsBySearch(q,"8dca7dea475e41e49518b2c61131e118",100)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends Articles>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends Articles> call(Throwable throwable) {
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Articles>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.i("stuck","complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    getNewsCallback.onError(new NetworkError(e));
                    Log.i("stuck",e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Articles articles) {
                    getNewsCallback.onSuccess(articles);
                    Log.i("stuck","Onnext");
                }
            });
}
```

}

Here is the Test class where I am stuck-

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class NewsListTest {

private NewsPresenter newsPresenter;

@Mock
private RxjavaService rxjavaService;
@Mock
private MainView mainView;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    newsPresenter = new NewsPresenter(rxjavaService,mainView);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mainView = null;
    newsPresenter.onStop();
}

@Test
public void Testing_The_Result() {

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for my bad grammar ; >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First things first

1. If you're into TDD, you'd never get into the situation you described. In TDD you **start** with a failing test, and just then go write the implementation. So your question is much more about testing then TDD.
2. I would recommend switching to RxJava2, as RxJava1 reaches End Of Life on March 31.
3. Look strange to me that `RxJavaService` changes the API from publish/subscribe to callbacks. Why not stick with rx API all the way to presenter?

### Test with mocked RxJavaService

If you'd like to finish writing the test with the setup you have in the test, it would look something like this:

```
@Test
public void Testing_The_Result() {
    final RxjavaService.GetNewsCallback[] callback = new RxjavaService.GetNewsCallback[1];
    Mockito.when(rxjavaService.getNews(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(RxjavaService.GetNewsCallback.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Subscription>() {
        public Subscription answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) {
            callback[0] = invocationOnMock.getArgument(1);
            return mock(Subscription.class);
        }
    });
    newsPresenter.getNewsList("some url");
    Articles articles = new Articles();

    callback[0].onSuccess(articles);

    verify(mainView).removeWait();
    verify(mainView).getNewsListSuccess(articles);
}
```

You can get rid of the ugly code by not using Mockito to mock `RxJavaService`, but rather roll you own hand-written mock, which would store the callback and provide it to the test.

However, I'd recommend a different approach.

### Test with real RxJavaService and mocked NewsRestService

I'd say it makes more sense and gives a better test if we mocked only the `NewsRestService`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class NewsList2Test {

    private NewsPresenter newsPresenter;

    @Mock
    private MainView mainView;
    @Mock
    private NewsRestService newsRestService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        newsPresenter = new NewsPresenter(new RxjavaService(newsRestService), mainView);
    }

    @Test
    public void show_success_in_view_when_there_are_articles() {
        when(newsRestService.getNewsBySearch(eq("some url"), anyString(), anyInt()))
                .thenReturn(Observable.just(new Articles()));

        newsPresenter.getNewsList("some url");

        verify(mainView).removeWait();
        verify(mainView).getNewsListSuccess(any(Articles.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir, Actually I am a beginner with TDD stuff. I just dive into it. Hence I got stuck here. I think I will start with the beginning for better understanding.